# Android Notification Problems When more than one

Tags: android, notifications

I build simple app with used GCM and notification, I already success implement that, but I have question about notification, in my case:

I got more than one notification, 
Example

> Notif_1 -> Title : test_1 , Message : test_message_1
>
> Notif_2 -> Title : test_2 , Message : test_message_2
>
> Notif_3 -> Title : test_3 , Message : test_message_3
>
> Notif_4 -> Title : test_4 , Message : test_message_4

The problem I just always got last notification bundle when I tap notification.

So when I tap `notif_1`, I got bundle from `notif_4`

when I tap `notif_2`, I got bundle from `notif_4`

What I want is when I tap `notif_1`, must have bundle from `notif_1` not from other notif

how to make like that?

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String msg) {
    mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ctx, BuyLevel.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("title", title);
    bundle.putString("message", msg);
    resultIntent.putExtras(bundle);

    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ctx);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(BuyLevel.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_mini);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg));
    mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    int initialNotification = CommonUtilities.msgId.incrementAndGet();

    mNotificationManager.notify(initialNotification, notification);
}
```

Comment: Post your code of How you generate notification?

Comment: i already edit my post

Comment: Check the value of "initialNotification". Are you getting the same value or different?

Comment: different value, because if i use same value, it will replace my old notification, and i dont want it.so i make always different value when make notification, but i dont know why i always just get last notif bundle, like i already explained in my case

Answer (score 1):

Flag must be required with unique values. So we can set flag as random number.
Change this line:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
Random random = new Random();
int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, m);
```

Comment: It works perfectly, does it have any negative effects?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of
>   PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories,
>   and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent
>   representing the same token if that is still valid.
>
> [...]
>
> A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent
>   objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents,
>   expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not
>   happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the
>   same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. **If you use two Intent
>   objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will
>   get the same PendingIntent for both of them.**
>
> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
>   the same time (*such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
>   at the same time*), then you will need to ensure there is something
>   that is different about them to associate them with different
>   PendingIntents.
>
> [...]
>
> This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by
>   Intent.filterEquals, or ***different request code integers*** supplied to
>   getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int,
>   Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or
>   getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

So your code when requesting the PendingIntent should be something like:

```
int m=0;
private void sendNotification(String title, String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           [...]
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(m++, 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           [...]
}
```